# Flutter web - Firebase cloud messaging - running OK on localhost, not when I upload to firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

I am trying to implement FCM for a flutter web project.

***When I run the project in the localhost, it works fine. But when I upload it to firebase hosting (After running flutter build web), I am getting errors.***

On the main.dart file, I am trying to get the device token:

```
final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(
      vapidKey:
          "my_key");
```

However, I am getting this error in the console:

```
main.dart.js:4430 Uncaught MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Messaging#getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
```

I added the firebase messaging package in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
 firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
```

Additionally, I added the service worker code as explained here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

Here is my index.html script code:

```
 <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
        // Download main.dart.js

        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
        }

        _flutter.loader
          .loadEntrypoint({
            serviceWorker: {
              serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
            },
          })
          .then(function (engineInitializer) {
            return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
          })
          .then(function (appRunner) {
            return appRunner.runApp();
          });
      });
    </script>
```

It looks like a problem with the firebase_messaging package, but I'm using the latest one. Also what I can't understand is why it's working in localhost but not production.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running **flutter clean** solved the problem